# HTML Input Validation using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to validate an html input which works on all platforms i.e. Chrome,Internet Explorer, Mozilla, Firefox, Safari & Opera for PC as well as iOS and Android.

I want to restrict the input to numbers between a particular range for eg (1 to 59). Also I have another input element in the same form. I also want to check if Input 1< Input 2, else give an error message. Please help.

I have tried the following two options which doesn't work on all platforms:

```
 <td align="center"><input  id="SH1" name="sh1" type="number" min="1"  max="59" align="center" /></td>
<td align="center"><input  id="SM1" name="sm1" type="text" maxlength="2" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' /></td>
```

Comment: On which browser the above code is not working??

Comment: I think the latest versions of firefox and google chrome does not support min max attributes.Use Javascript or Jquery instead

Comment: Where's your JavaScript? You need to show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

To compatible with almost every browser, use native JavaScript. An simple example for your requirement is follows.

```
<script language="javascript">
  function validate() {
    var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('val1').value);
    var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('val2').value);

    minMaxRange(val1, val2);
    comparison(val1, val2);
  }

  function minMaxRange(value1, value2) {
    if (value1 < 1 || value2 < 1) {
      alert("Minimum value should be 1");
    }

    if (value1 > 59 || value2 > 59) {
      alert("Maximum value should be 59");
    }
  }

  function comparison(value1, value2) {
    if (value1 > value2) {
      alert("Value2 should be greater than Value1");
    }
  }

</script>

<body>
  <p><span>Value 1 : </span>
    <input type="text" id="val1">
  </p>
  <p><span>Value 2 : </span>
    <input type="text" id="val2">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="button" value="Validate" onClick="validate()">
  </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's say there are two inputs as follow

```
<input id="input1" type="number">
<input type="input2" type="number">
```

Now the JS:(Using jQuery)

```
if($("#input1").val()<1 || $("#input1").val()>59)
    alert("Error");

if($("#input1").val() < $("#input2").val())
    alert("Error");
```

Remember to include jQuery library before this code.

Now if you want to check it during input do following;

```
 $("[id^=input]").keyUp(function(){

    if($("#input1").val()<1 || $("#input1").val()>59)
      alert("Error");

    if($("#input1").val() < $("#input2").val())
       alert("Error");
})
```